# how i can access the list forms that are being rendered inside mobile devices

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-designer, mobile

I am working on a Team site collection and i enabled "Mobile Browser View" feature. Now inside the site i have issue tracking list. now when i access the list's new & edit forms from my mobile device, i noted that they have different names compared to the regular forms.. so my question is from where i can access and modify the forms that are being rendered from the mobile devices , i can not see them inside the SharePoint designer ?

Comment: check this one https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb861936%28v=office.14%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE so this can not be done using sharepoint designer or another tool ?

Comment: I am not sure about it because I never tried it....rather we don't have such requirement

Comment: so you mean you do not access sharepoint from mobile devices ?

Comment: yes becuase this is not requirement....but i can if i want,

Comment: seems there are many problems when using mobile views,i though this will be supported out-of-the-box.. for example all the "People or group" column types will not have the autocomplete feature unlike the pc view, so you have to type username manually !!.. also we have an enterprise wiki site collection and if you try to view a standard wiki page (i mean a wiki page where i did not apply any customization), then the wiki page will be shown as a white page (blank page) !!

Comment: i am sorry, but i  dont have experince with Mobile devices...One thing as per my experince, SharePoint customization is real pain.

Comment: @WaqasSarwarMCSE i do not mind if it is real pain ,, but on some situation it can not be done !!!  especially for the enterprise wiki where all the wiki pages will be shown as blank pages on the mobile devices!!